# Linux Mint crashes when I connect a new screen

Tags: linux-mint, display

I have an HP laptop, the reference is Elitebook 840 G3. I'm running on Linux Mint 18 Sarah 32 bits.
After several months of usage, everything works like a charm except the dual screen.

Every time I plug in a new screen device, the computer completely crashes and I have to do a hard reboot. It happens no matter what display device I use, from typical monitors to overhead devices.

The only workaround for me is to close the laptop's lid, wait for the computer to shut down and then plug the VGA cable. But every time I connect other displays while running, it crashes.

Any ideas what it could come from?

Comment: Please add the desktop environment (Cinnamon, Xfce, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.

I tried un-installing and re-installing the intel driver called `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and for some reason after rebooting it worked properly. I don't really understand the reasons, but a simple graphic driver re-install works !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a GPU(graphic Card) Driver Issue? 
Try to Update everything,

and then Check the loaded driver with this i think:

For Nvidia: `lsmod | grep nv`

For ATI:    `lsmod | grep radeon`

Or maybe try a other Cable than VGA?

Or if you want to use VGA, try a different VGA cable.